# Dozer with EJB 3.1 in TomEE

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.1, dozer

I am using EJB 3.1 in TomEE, I wanted to use a mapper so I choosed DOZER.
Here is the implementation :

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class DozerInstantiator {
private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DozerInstantiator.class);

public enum States {BEFORESTARTED, STARTED, PAUSED, SHUTTINGDOWN};
private States state;
private DozerBeanMapper mapper;

  @PostConstruct   
public void initialize() throws Throwable {       
log.info("---------------Dozer  Starting Up-----------------");
        try{
            state = States.BEFORESTARTED;
            this.mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
         } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error("Cause: " + e.getCause());
                log.error("Message: " + e.getMessage());
                log.error("Class: " + e.getClass());
                log.error("StackTrace: " + e.getStackTrace());
                throw e;
            }
        log.info("---------------Dozer  Started-----------------");   }

  public DozerBeanMapper getMapper() {
    return mapper;   }

}
```

Here is the EJB where I want to inject Dozer :

```
@Stateless(name = "randomName")
@WebService(targetNamespace = "urn:x1:x2")
@Local
@TransactionAttribute(javax.ejb.TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class RandomEJBImpl  implements RandomEJB {

@EJB
DozerInstantiator di;

        public ListOutput getAllConf() throws ServiceException {
            try {
                // code         
                objMapped = di.getMapper().map(obj, X.class);
                // more code
                }
                return listOutput 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Failed in RandomEJBImpl.getAllConf: "+e); 
                return null;
            }
        } 
 }
```

I have 2 questions :

1- If I try to start the server with the previous DozerInstantiator  configuration , the application crash as you can see here, until i realized that if I remove @PostConstruct it will start; can you explain to me why is that ?

```
INFO  09-08 14:57:17,032 [main]: (DozerInstantiator.java:initialize:35)  ----------------Dozer  Starting Up-----------------
ERROR 09-08 14:57:17,093 [main]: (DozerInstantiator.java:initialize:41)  -Cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
ERROR 09-08 14:57:17,094 [main]: (DozerInstantiator.java:initialize:42)  -Message: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
ERROR 09-08 14:57:17,095 [main]: (DozerInstantiator.java:initialize:43)  -Class: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
ERROR 09-08 14:57:17,095 [main]: (DozerInstantiator.java:initialize:44)  -StackTrace: [Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@7856e1fc
```

2- So after removing @PostConstruct from DozerInstantiator 
i have the following error in logfile ... How can I avoid it ?

```
ERROR 09-08 14:34:12,948 [http-8080-2]: (RandomEJBImpl.getAllConf:830)  -Failed in Failed in RandomEJBImpl.getAllConf: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Since you've removed `@PostConstuct`, the `init()` is never called, so `getMapper()` returns `null`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I tried to catch exception for the @PostConstuct Part, and updated the question 1 with more logs... can you please help ?

Comment: You don't seem to have apache-commons 3 library in your app classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to set in conf/system.properties the line: openejb.classloader.forced-load=org.apache.commons.lang3 to enable lang3 to be loaded from the webapp and not let tomee skip the webapp to use container lang3 version